# null value in column "x" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I making a feature where one user can follow another. I had this working momentarily but then it broke again (I got some assistance from a mentor). I am trying to trouble shoot it myself but can't figure out what is happening even though the error is pretty clear what is going wrong, I can't fix it.

Error:

```
null value in column "followed_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (46, null, null).
```

The model is:

```
class UserConnections(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The serializer is:

```
class UserConnectionListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserConnections
        fields = ['follower','followed']

class UserConnectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserConnections
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2
```

My view is:

```
class UserConnectionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserConnectionListSerializer
    queryset = UserConnections.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = {'follower': request.DATA.get('follower_id'), 'followed': request.DATA.get('followed_id')}

            serializer = UserConnectionListSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

FWIW I am passing the Ids to the view view an AJAX call and it is definitely passing through two integers.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do note that `request.DATA` has been deprecated since DRF version 3.0 (and removed since version 3.2) you should be using `request.data` instead. Furthermore as the name `get_serializer_class` suggests you are supposed to return the serializer class in that method, yet you do much more and return a `Response`, this obviously will give you an error.

Comment: Ok thanks I have cleaned it up based on your feedback and now the error is this: ``NameError: name 'UserConnectionListSerializer' is not defined``